# Simulating web site with remembered user in selenium

Tags: selenium, authentication

I'm collecting user actions from a web page. For example; [www.test.com/home](http://www.test.com/home). After that I'm simulating user's actions in same page with selenium. But user logged in test.com and browser remember this(with cookie, storage, firebase, google account etc. Doesn't matter).

When I open [www.test.com/home](http://www.test.com/home) with selenium in another server, of course browser doesn't remember  user's login credentials and opening login page.

Is there any way simulating a page in another server with remembered user.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006943/why-chrome-doesnt-show-save-password-or-remember-password-option-while-running

Comment: Thanks for the response. It will work for sites whose authentication information is stored in the cookies. But for other methods, for example google acount auth, this won't work. I need more comprehensive solution.